# nodejs - Express request shape zip from geoserver return text

Tags: node.js, express, shapefile, geoserver

I am requesting a geoserver from express (node.js) for getting shape zip in wfs service, but I just got text.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require("request");
var DOWNLOAD_DIR = './downloads/';
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var file_url='https://geo.gob.bo/geoserver/aasana/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&typeName=aerodromos&outputFormat=shape-zip';
 request(file_url, function(err, resp, body) {
console.log('res',res);
     console.log('body',body);
if(!err){
         var file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + 'aerodromos');
         var buff = new Buffer(body);
          file.write(buff,function(err){
              console.log(err);
          });
           file.end();
            console.log(' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);
     }else{
         console.log("No results error.",err);
     }
 });
  res.render('index', { title: 'descargado' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am trying to put into a file zip but I cant open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set encoding to null which will be treated as buffer rather than string in your case

```
request({url: file_url, encoding: null}, function(err, resp, body) {
```